# Laravel reverse routing benefits

Tags: laravel, routes

As per [this](https://www.onlineinterviewquestions.com/reverse-routing-laravel/#.W2snZt8xBCU) link, we have been told that with reverse routing, we can generate links. But Laravel already provides `named routing` for the same. As well as there is another way to generate link is the `route` helper function.

Then what is actual benefit of using reverse routing in Laravel?

Comment: Never seen that usage, but I wonder how it handles multiple routes mapped to the same controller function. That aside, named routes, and even the `url()` helper seem like perfectly acceptable alternatives.

Comment: Yeah, thought so. Thanks @TimLewis

Answer (score 2):

Laravel reverse routing benefit should be apparent. Say you want to change your login URL to users/signin, if you aren't using named routes you'd have to go through and manually change all URLs to point to the new URL. That's a lot of wasted time. With named routes you simply change the route in routes.php and all of your links will now point to the new UR.

You can check this link for detail description about reverse routing. 
http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-reverse-routing

Comment: No, I don't see the benefit over the named routing,

Answer (score 2):

Why nobody is referring this --> `{{route('user.login')}}` while you declared this name to route. Can we say this is a reverse routing?

Just you have to declare the following:

```
Route::get('login', 'users@login')->name('user.login');
```

Comment: is this reverse routing?

Comment: what you are looking for exactly ?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. This seems to be asking for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

is this reverse routing.. I always use action helper :: `{{ action('HomeController@index') }}`

Comment: Probably Yes! without defining the route in the routes file and when you hover on the link it says http:\\Yousite.com\redirect. 
That redirect word means its reverse routing.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. This seems to be asking for clarification.